# Delete rows from two tables with same primary key

Tags: java, mysql, sql, sql-delete

I have two tables:

Table1: `orders`

```
idOrder, 
Blockquote
idUser
```

Table2: `ordersinfo`

```
idOrder,
.......,
.......
```

`idOrder` is primary a key for two tables. I have to delete from this tables rows by `idUser`. I tried different ways, but nothing helped me.

**My Questions:** What query, I should use?

I have this exception

> MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException

Comment: Try to remove ordersInfo first before you remove orders, because it has a foreign key to orders. Can you try that?

Comment: We can guess, but you need to provide information about what constraint is being violated, for us to be able to know what the problem is.

Comment: Some databases implement a cascading delete. You can investigate this.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to issue two delete statement

```
-- Delete OrderInfo table 
DELETE FROM ordersinfo
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM orders
              WHERE orders.idOrder = ordersinfo.idOrder 
              AND IdUser = ???)

-- Delete Orders 
DELETE FROM Orders 
WHERE IdUser = ???
```

Comment: I have this exception:  MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '--Delete OrderInfo table 
DELETE FROM ordersinfo WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1         ' at line 1